# Why do I keep getting a 500 error with my PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create an account registration page and when I add a system to check the database and make sure that there are not multiple rows with the same username, I get a 500 error.

Here's the code that works:

```
<?php


if(isset ($_POST['submit']))
{
    include( 'connection.php' );

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if(empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password))
    {
        echo 'Please check the required fields.';
    }
    elseif(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        echo 'Please enter a correct email address.';
    }
    else
    {
        $password = md5($password);
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (email,username,password) VALUES ('$email','$username','$password')") or die(mysql_error());

        if($sql)
        {
            echo 'Successfully submitted.';
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

Here's the code that gives me a 500 error:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL)

if(isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
    include( 'connection.php' );

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$email'") or die(mysql_error();
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($fetch);

    if(empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password)) {
        echo 'Please check the required fields.';
    }
    elseif(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo 'Please enter a correct email address.';
    }

    elseif($num_rows >= 1);
    {
        echo 'This username is taken.';

    else    
    }
        $password = md5($password);
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (email,username,password) VALUES ('$email','$username','$password')") or die(mysql_error());

        if($sql)
        {
            echo 'Successfully submitted.';
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: Have a look in the error log file if you have access to it

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please look at mysql_real_escape_string, or consider PDO.

Comment: if you have installed php-cgi on your local PC then you could at least do a `php -l` to check you code for errors.  It took me 60s to find the same errors as at @Jocelyn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a semi-colon off your first statement

Answer (score 3):

Maybe add a semi colon:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

EDIT:

You are also missing a `)` on `die(mysql_error();`

Remove the `;` from `elseif($num_rows >= 1);`

And then fix your `else` block to be `} else {`

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
else }
```

in your code. That's a syntax error. You're looking for

```
}
else {
```

instead.