# 500 error on PHP page

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I keep getting a 500 error with my PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379016/why-do-i-keep-getting-a-500-error-with-my-php)

I am creating a page that allows a user to login to the website. I keep getting a 500 error. Here's the code that gives me an error:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    include( 'connection.php' );

    if(empty($username) || empty($password))
    {
        $error = 'Please enter your username and password'
    }
    else
    {
        $password = md5($password);
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $username AND password = $password LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error)();
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

        if($num_rows == 1)
        {
            $fetch = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
            extract ($fetch);
            echo $username;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'There was an error while logging in'
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041), into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain).

Comment: Also, as stated in the PHP manual for the [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function: *Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.*

Comment: i see a couple of potential errors in the code already:

1. there is no "ifset" function in php, so it should be "isset". 

2. in the sql query, the variables $username and $password should be enclosed in quotes since they are string values. e.g. mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1"). So I think you should eliminate those basic errors and then try to figure out if there is something additional thats causing this 500 error.

Comment: @tereško I am not spamming, I am a beginner. Please learn the differences before you accuse me of spamming.

Comment: @Radu: Perhaps you should address that to the OP :) I don't need to know that..

Answer (score 2):

During **development** you can set in you php.ini:

- error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
- display_errors = On
- display_startup_errors = On

then in most cases you will see error description instead of blank page.

If you still getting blank page then:

- log_errors = On
- error_log = php_errors.log

and there is a chance that php_errors.log will have some description.

IHMO the best idea is using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/).

Answer (score 1):

`ifset()` isn't a function. You're looking for `isset()`.

Comment: Fixed, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `or die(mysql_error)();` should also be `or die(mysql_error());`, but as others have mentioned, using `mysql_error` is not a good idea.

Comment: I removed `mysql_error` but still no luck.

Comment: For clarification, how does that line look now?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $username AND password = $password LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```